# Action buttons for mobile -- ok to go full width?

Tags: mobile, buttons, design-patterns, android, iphone

Is it acceptable to use full width mobile action buttons, say in the footer, like in the 1st example? It's nice and simple but I'm afraid users might mistake it for a regular footer. The 2nd example might better signal that it's a button but has a lot of dead space.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are designing for Android, a full width button similar to the first is okay if you are using a borderless button theme, but if not, it would need to be more like the second. Take a look at the [Button design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/buttons.html).

If you are talking about iOS, then it would need to be a button more like the second.

However, neither of them are fantastic as they stand.  If you design for Android, you need to make it look more like an android button, and the same goes for iOS. **Neither of those two options look much like an Android or iOS button**.

Android buttons:
[image]

iOS button example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need a visual relief around the button to be seen as a button. If you make it full-width then I wouldn't see the button anymore and I would rather take "text" is a hyperlink or substitute of a button but on Mobile Apps, we expect buttons to be action triggers instead of text.

**Conclusion:** don't use full-width and let your buttons be seen and taken as buttons.